# Can I design the UI in Xamarin.Forms by using XAML

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a cross platform app using Xamarin.Forms. As far as I know, the UI will be created from the code and the .axml file will be generated automatically.

Can I modify the .axml file to edit the UI? I tried editing but all that comes up is what is written in the code. ie: `hello forms`

**UPDATE**

```
public static Page GetMainPage ()
        {   
            return new simplerow ();
        }
```

Comment: Its hard to tell from your update what is / what isn't working.  If you want to send across your project I will take a look?  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: @Pete I will post the full code here tomorrow.Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Pete Here is the link to the xamarin.forms project https://www.dropbox.com/s/myhuun5fp3rrd70/testforms.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'm getting an error when compiling as the test.xml is empty.  By the looks of it though in App.cs in testforms Shared Project you are wanting to return a page from the Android platform-specific project.  This is not what your going to want to be doing.  All your layouts you will write will be in Xamarin.Forms and will reside in the testforms Shared Project instead, as these are common pages that will be used in different platform specific projects, i.e. iOS and Windows Phone also.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.test.xml was not empty,it might not have saved.Okay so i will need to write the layout in Xamarin.forms and place it under testforms rather than testforms.android.Can you please write a simple xamarin.forms layout in the project i have sent you.Now im fairy confused with this.Can Xamarin.forms Layout be written in XAML

Comment: If you load up the project in the link I gave for *XAML pages* [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/XAMLSamples) they have lots of pages that you can copy their code example in just XAML.  Yes - put the page in the Shared Project (testforms) and not in the platform-specific project (testforms.Android).  Take a look as you should be able to do this ok I think.

Comment: @Pete Thanks.I can write XAML but where to put it under testforms  and what name should i give it and how to create content page from XAML.Is XAML=Xamarin.Forms Layout file?

Comment: Try creating a new XAML page in the testforms (Shared Project) at the project root.  The code-behind will derive from ContentPage, and the XAML part you can just copy from one of there examples.  In you App.cs you create and return a new instance of the code-behind class name that is used.  Yes - the XAML = a layout file written in XAML that uses Xamarin.Forms markup.  Forget about any android markup etc as that is platform-specific.  The link that I have if you inspect some of their XAML pages it will help you.

Comment: @Pete Just downloaded an example project from xamarin and now i understand.Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Xamarin.Forms** you can create your pages from markup definitions that are shared across all platforms.

Typically you will write all your content pages using **Xamarin.Forms**, however you can mix-and-match native pages into an application should you so wish.

These shared common pages, written in **Xamarin.Forms**, will reside maybe in a **PCL** project, or a **Shared Project** so these can then be re-used in the *platform-specific* projects, each targeting *a specific platform OS*.

You can write these common pages, either in *code*, or in **XAML**.  You can even choose to write some pages one way, and some the other if you so choose.

A **Xamarin.Forms** page is processed at runtime through the interpretation of  the page composition that has been created.

Each control that is specified on a page, has its own platform specific renderer, behind the scenes, that will produce output that is targetted to that **OS**.

When writing **Xamarin.Forms** pages, for-the-most, you will start to learn a new way of creating pages that is abstracted from the intricacies of creating mobile applications on each different platform **OS**.

There is therefore **no** editable **.axml** that is generated etc as you will write your pages using **Xamarin.Forms** markup and controls, and even your own or other custom-controls to produce your own application pages.

The following [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/XAMLSamples/) shows some examples of how to write **XAML** pages.

The following [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/FormsGallery/) shows some examples of how to write from **code-behind** pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,this makes things much clear.Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the previous answer re: .xaml instead of .axml, you need to remember to change the startup code in app.cs to use your new .xaml form. Replace the "new ContentPage {...};" with "new MyForm();" (where "MyForm" is the name of your shiny new XAML form).

EDIT: Downloaded the project from the dropbox link. Comments below...

I see several issues here. I think you may need to go through the walkthroughs and sample applications provided by Xamarin to get up to speed with the concepts behind XF apps.

First, you are trying to use an Activity as your application's page. In a Xamarin Forms app, it must be a View of some sort, not a platform-specific visual such as Activity.

Second, remove the "test.xml" file from your Android project's Resources/layout folder; while XAML files are indeed XML, they have an 1) have a file extension of .xaml and 2) belong in the shared project.

Here's what you need to do to get your project working: (I'm assuming you're using VS here, under Xamarin Studio, it's slightly different.)

1. Right-click your "testforms" shared project
2. Click Add from the context menu and select "New Item"
3. In the dialog that appears, select "Forms XAML Page" and in the Name area enter a name (such as "MyForm")
   (If you're using XS, choose "New File" and "Forms ContentPage")
4. This will add two files to your project: a XAML file containing your layout (e.g.: MyForm.xaml), and a code-behind file (e.g.: MyForm.xaml.cs).
5. Open the XAML file, and modify the Label element so that the Text attribute is

   Text = "Hello, World!"
6. Modify the body of GetMainPage in your App.cs to the following:

   return new MyForm();
7. Run the app

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.Finally i can use XAML which i know to design the UI :)

Comment: I tried this and updated the code in app.cs file to create a ui from simplerow.xml.But simplerow is not recognized.Please see the update.

Comment: Is it just failing to compile? What does your XAML look like? Have you included the namespace that your form's codebehind class  is in?

Comment: Its failing to compile.im out of office,will post the code around same time tomorrow.

Comment: Please download the project from dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/myhuun5fp3rrd70/testforms.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong. Forms are created either through code or XAML. No axml or anything persistent is generated at platform level, everything is done in runtime(XAML is sort of compiled at compile time).

So, modify either code or XAML if you wish to change something. Or, if you need something more demanding, than consider either subclassing an existing Renderer or create you own.

Comment: Thanks.So if i need to create a Xamarin.Forms app,i can create the UI using XAML ie:by editing the Main.axml file like we do in Android Apps.But i modified like this and the change is not reflected,all that comes is the basic hello forms message.Please let me know if you need the code

Comment: No, there is no axml. XAML is platform agnostic for Forms. [Read more here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: "(XAML is sort of compiled at compile time)" is sort of wrong :)

Comment: Well, I don't know what exact transformation you are doing at MSBuild level and then at runtime, hence I wrote "sort of". Perhaps you are just embedding XAML content, possibly binary optimized or something? Anyway I am all ears if you wish to go into details :)

Comment: @MihaMarkic: the only MSBuild transformation is the generation of the partial class, containing InitializeComponent () and field definitions. Look for files with .xaml.g.cs in your obj/Debug folder.

Comment: I see, I thought you were doing something more. Anyway, I am still correct, though, as Custom Tool says "MSBuild:Compile" ;-)